# JSON.parse で uninitialized constant JSON というエラーが出る

Tags: ruby, json

bitFlyerのAPIで、ある値の情報を抜き取りたいです。

APIの`getchildorders`の中にある`child_order_state`の値を取り出して、`COMPLETED`の場合は`yes`と表示させたいのですが、エラーになってします。宜しくお願い致します。

エラーコード

> 25:in `': uninitialized constant JSON (NameError)

サンプルコード

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "openssl"
key = "ほげほげ"
secret = "ほげほげ"
timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
method = "GET"
uri = URI.parse("https://api.bitflyer.jp")
uri.path = "/v1/me/getchildorders"
uri.query = "product_code=FX_BTC_JPY&count=after&after=ほげほげ"
text = timestamp + method + uri.request_uri
sign = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256"), secret, text)
options = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {
"ACCESS-KEY" => key,
"ACCESS-TIMESTAMP" => timestamp,
"ACCESS-SIGN" => sign,
});
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
response = https.request(options)
puts response.body

json = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
getchildorders = JSON.parse(json)

puts getchildorders["child_order_state"]
getchildorders["child_order_state"] = COMPLETED
puts yes
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/114610

Answer (score 2):

JSON クラスは json ライブラリを読み込まないと使えません。
プログラムの先頭の方に次のように書いておけばいいと思います。

```
require "json"
```

Comment: ありがつございます。忘れてましたｗ。修正して動かしてみたら違うエラーが出てきてしまいました。uninitialized constant COMPLETED (NameError)
Did you mean?  Complex

Comment: getchildorders["child_order_state"] = COMPLETED という行で COMPLETED という定数の値を代入していますが、そのような定数はどこにも定義されていないため NameError が発生しています。 if 文や比較が書けていないということは Ruby という言語の基本的な文法についての知識が欠落していると思われるので一度書籍や学習サイトなどで知識を補われるとよいかと思われます。

Comment: すみません　if getchildorders["child_order_state"] = COMPLETED です。記入漏れです。