# 変数を比較するところでエラー: uninitialized constant BUY (NameError)

Tags: ruby

jsonで値を取得して、変数に代入をして、その変数との比較をするときに、初期化されていない定数と出てエラーになります。a == BUY　の時、"yes" と表示させたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "openssl"
require "json"

key = "kkkkkkkkkkkkk"
secret = "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"

timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
method = "GET"
uri = URI.parse("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk")
uri.path = "/v1/me/getpositions"
uri.query = "product_code=kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"

text = timestamp + method + uri.request_uri
sign = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256"), secret, text)

options = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {
                             "ACCESS-KEY" => key,
                             "ACCESS-TIMESTAMP" => timestamp,
                             "ACCESS-SIGN" => sign,
                             });

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
response = https.request(options)

json = response.body
getpositions = JSON.parse(json)


a = getpositions[0]["side"]

if a == BUY　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＃ここでエラーになります
puts "yes"
```

エラーコード

```
a.rb:34:in `<main>': uninitialized constant BUY (NameError)
```

Comment: 重複候補: [JSON.parse で uninitialized constant JSON というエラーが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41910/json-parse-%e3%81%a7-uninitialized-constant-json-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e5%87%ba%e3%82%8b)

Answer (score 3):

bitFlyer APIの [getpositions](https://lightning.bitflyer.jp/docs?lang=ja&_ga=2.203656272.1325053266.1522402812-166515414.1515686097#%E5%BB%BA%E7%8E%89%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97) にリクエストを送って返ってくるJSONは以下の様なフォーマットで、この中で目的の`"BUY"`は「**文字列**」です。

```
[
  {
    "product_code": "FX_BTC_JPY",
    "side": "BUY",
    "price": 36000,
    ... ,
  }
]
```

変数`a`の中身が`BUY`という文字列かを確認するのであれば、以下のような記述にする必要があります。

```
if a == "BUY" then
    puts "yes"
```

比較の際にダブルクォートでくくらない記述だと、`BUY`という**定数**(=変数)とみなして参照しようとしますが、どこにも定義がされていないので実際に実行されたときのように'定数が初期化されていない'というエラーになります。